# Why am I getting the error: No overload matches this call. Overload 1 of 3 in my Typescript project?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript, redux, types

I'm receiving the following error:

(property) hero: Reducer
No overload matches this call.
Overload 1 of 3, '(reducers: ReducersMapObject): Reducer, AnyAction>', gave the following error.

Type '(state: string | undefined, action: Action) => string | Hero' is not assignable to type 'Reducer'.
Types of parameters 'state' and 'state' are incompatible.
Type 'Hero | undefined' is not assignable to type 'string | undefined'.

Type 'Hero' is not assignable to type 'string'.ts(2769)
index.ts(7, 3): The expected type comes from property 'hero' which is declared here on type 'ReducersMapObject'

It appears on the 'hero' written in index.ts below with the 3 asterix either side of it.

reducers/index.ts:

```
import { combineReducers } from "redux";
import { heroesReducer, heroReducer } from "./reducer";
import { Hero } from "../actions";

export interface StoreState {
  heroes: Hero[];
  hero: Hero;
}

export const reducers = combineReducers<StoreState>({
  heroes: heroesReducer,
  ***hero***: heroReducer
});
```

reducers/reducers.ts

```
import { Hero, Action, ActionTypes } from "../actions";

export const heroesReducer = (state: Hero[] = [], action: Action) => {
  switch (action.type) {
    case ActionTypes.fetchAllHeroes:
      return action.payload;

    default:
      return state;
  }
};

export const heroReducer = (state: Hero, action: Action) => {
  switch (action.type) {
    case ActionTypes.fetchSingleHero:
      return action.payload;

    default:
      return state;
  }
};
```

actions/types.ts

```
import { FetchAllHeroesAction, FetchSingleHeroAction } from "./heroes";

export enum ActionTypes {
  fetchAllHeroes,
  fetchSingleHero,
  searchHero
}

export type Action = FetchAllHeroesAction | FetchSingleHeroAction;
```

components/HeroItem:

```
import React from "react";
import { StoreState } from "../reducers";
import { connect } from "react-redux";
import { Hero, fetchSingleHero } from "../actions";

interface HeroProps {
  id: string;
  hero: Hero;
}

export const _HeroItem: React.FC<HeroProps> = props => {
  console.log(props);

  return <div>{props.hero}hihihihi</div>;
};

const mapStateToProps = (state: StoreState): { hero: Hero } => {
  return { hero: state.hero };
};

export const HeroItem = connect(mapStateToProps, { fetchSingleHero })(
  _HeroItem
);
```

actions/heroes.ts:

```
import axios from "axios";
import { Dispatch } from "redux";
import { ActionTypes } from "./types";

export interface Hero {
  id: string;
  name: string;
  powerstats: {
    strength: string;
    speed: string;
    intelligence: string;
    durability: string;
    power: string;
    combat: string;
  };

  biography: {
    fullName: string;
    alterEgos: string;
    aliases: string[];
    placeOfBirth: string;
    publisher: string;
    alignment: string;
  };

  appearance: {
    gender: string;
    race: string;
    height: string[];
    weight: string[];
  };

  work: {
    occupation: string;
    base: string;
  };

  connections: {
    groupAffiliation: string;
    relatives: string;
  };

  image: {
    url: string;
  };
}


export interface FetchSingleHeroAction {
  type: ActionTypes.fetchSingleHero;
  payload: Hero;
}

export interface HeroId {
  id: string;
}

export const fetchSingleHero = (heroId: HeroId) => {
  const url = `https://superheroapi.com/api/2987607971258652/${heroId}`;

  return async (dispatch: Dispatch) => {
    const res = await axios.get(corsProxy + url);
    console.log(res.data);
    dispatch<FetchSingleHeroAction>({
      type: ActionTypes.fetchSingleHero,
      payload: res.data
    });
  };
};
```

I got it working for a 'FetchAllHeroes' action last night but did it by deleting part of a prop checking typescript component which I think isn't the best way. If anyone has any ideas on how to fix it or wants any other information to help it would be greatly appreciated. I'm very new to Typescript.

Thanks!

Comment: What's the type of `Action` mentioned in reducers.ts ?

Comment: Hi, thanks a lot for taking the time to try and help. I've updated the question to include the Action mentioned.

Comment: Not entirely sure if I'm right about this but `type Action = FetchAllHeroesAction | FetchSingleHeroAction` seems to think that `Actrion.payload` is either `Hero` or `string` maybe from the (unmentioned here) `FetchAllHeroesAction`. Personally I use [Typesafe actions](https://github.com/piotrwitek/typesafe-actions) to deal with redux because I don't fully understand it myself.

Comment: Hi and thanks again. I don't think its that unfortunately, I've just temporarily removed all the references to FetchAllHeroesAction from the code and still got the same error :(